# Group books and get count for each of their ratings

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have a Rating model with a book and rating value to it. I would like to get all the ratings count (ratings vary from 1 to 5) for each book in the database.

My schema simply looks like -

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("57e112312a52fe257e5d1d5c"),
      "book": ObjectId("57e111142a52fe257e5d1d42"),
      "rating": 4
    }
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("57e7a002420d22d6106a4715"),
      "book": ObjectId("57e111142a52fe257e5d1d42"),
      "rating": 5
    }
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("57e7a4cd98bfdb5a11962d54"),
      "book": ObjectId("57e111142a52fe257e5d17676"),
      "rating": 5
    }
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("57e7a4cd98bfdb5a11962d54"),
      "book": ObjectId("57e111142a52fe257e5d17676"),
      "rating": 1
    }
```

Currently, i have only been able to get to this point where i can get the no of ratings for each book but it doesn't specify exactly the rating value count.

This is my current query -

```
    db.ratings.aggregate([
        {$match: {book: {$in: [ObjectId("57e111142a52fe257e5d1d42"), ObjectId('57e6bef7cad79fa38555c643')]}}},
        {$group: {_id: {book: "$book", value: "$value"} } },
        {$group: {_id: "$_id.book", total: {$sum: 1}}},
    ])
```

The output is this -

```
    {
        "result": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("57e6bef7cad79fa38555c643"),
                "total": 2
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("57e111142a52fe257e5d1d42"),
                "total": 2
            }
        ],
        "ok": 1
    }
```

However, i want to club all the documents and get a result with the count of ratings for each value of the `rating` field, something like below. The whole point is that i just want the count of ratings for each value for each book.

```
    {
        result: [
            {
                _id: "57e111142a52fe257e5d17676",
                5_star_ratings: 1,
                4_star_ratings: 3,
                3_star_ratings: 4,
                2_star_ratings: 1,
                1_star_ratings: 0,
            },
            {
                _id: "57e111142a52fe257e5d1d42",
                5_star_ratings: 10,
                4_star_ratings: 13,
                3_star_ratings: 7,
                2_star_ratings: 8,
                1_star_ratings: 19,
            }
            .
            .
            .
            .
        ]
    }
```

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accomplishing the task require a **`$group`** pipeline that uses the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator in the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator operator. The **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator will evaluate a logical condition based on its first argument (if) and then returns the second argument where the evaluation is true (then) or the third argument where false (else). This converts the true/false logic into 1 and 0 numerical values that feed into **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** respectively:

```
{
    "$sum": { 
        "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$rating", 1 ] }, 1, 0 ]
    }
}
```

As a resulting operation, you might want to run the following aggregation pipeline:

```
var pipeline = [
    { 
        "$match": {
            "book": {
                "$in": [
                    ObjectId("57e111142a52fe257e5d1d42"), 
                    ObjectId('57e6bef7cad79fa38555c643')
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$book",             
            "5_star_ratings": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$rating", 5 ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "4_star_ratings": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$rating", 4 ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "3_star_ratings": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$rating", 3 ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "2_star_ratings": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$rating", 2 ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "1_star_ratings": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$rating", 1 ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }           
        }  
    },
]

db.ratings.aggregate(pipeline)
```

---

For a more flexible and better performant approach which executes much faster than the above, consider running an alternative pipeline as follows

```
db.ratings.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "book": {
                "$in": [
                    ObjectId("57e111142a52fe257e5d1d42"), 
                    ObjectId('57e6bef7cad79fa38555c643')
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "book": "$name",
                "rating": "$rating"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.book",
            "counts": {
                "$push": {
                    "rating": "$_id.rating",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: oh my god, that worked like a charm, thank you so very much. Do you think this is a heavy operation and if there is a room for optimisation?

Comment: @ktkaushik I would like to think there is room for improvement. Consider another approach that does not use the hashed key approach as an alternative. Will update my answer with that approach in a bit.

Comment: Yeah, i mean that approach can be knocked off from the requirement and that's not a problem

Comment: How can I add I next stage to get the average rating for a book @chridam?

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett That's a good question, I would suggest you create a new post with that and I am more than happy to answer

Comment: I posted the question. Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440813/mongoose-aggregate-to-get-average-rating-count-each-rate-and-return-the-actual @chridam